# Disable Sidebar on certain pages

Tags: custom-post-types, php, pages, sidebar

Good day!

How do you disable/remove sidebars in certain pages? Do I need to install a plugin(what plugin)? Or should I do a custom code?

Thanks.

Comment: This would be something your theme would need to support. Since 3rd-party themes are off topic here, I'd suggest contacting the theme author.

Answer (score 0):

You could use these plugins:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-sidebars/
- https://jetpack.com/support/widget-visibility/

Both allow you to control which widgets/sidebars show up where.

Comment: The problem with custom-sidebars is that it leaves my sidebar empty, what I wanted to happen was to completely remove the sidebar on a certain page/post.